# Error installing the Data Exchange Framework - Exception processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event

Tags: packages, data-exchange-framework

The actual error encountered is:

> One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

This error appears to be related to the fact that the Sitecore Publishing Framework 1.8.0 module or SXA is installed.

[image: Installation error]

### Installation Steps

- Install Sitecore 8.2 initial release
- Install `Sitecore Publishing Service 1.8.0.zip`
- Install `Data Exchange Framework 1.1.0 rev. 160817.zip`
- Install `Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 1.1.0 rev. 160817.zip`
- Install `Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.1 for Sitecore 8.zip`
- Install `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.1 rev. 161004 for 8.2.zip`
- Reinstall `Data Exchange Framework 1.1.0 rev. 160817.zip`. Error!

**Note:** Could probably encounter the error sooner. Will try to duplicate with fewer steps.

### Logs

So I finally tracked down the log files for the installation. Wasn't quite sure which detail to leave out.

> ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:01 INFO  Job started: Install
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing package: C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Data\packages\Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 1.1.0 rev. 160817.zip
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.Local.config
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\bin\Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.dll
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\bin\Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.Local.dll
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\temp\Sitecore\da-DK.xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\temp\Sitecore\de-DE.xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:02 INFO  Installing C:\Websites\demo.dev.local\Website\temp\Sitecore\ja-JP.xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/{548EB4E1-0CCD-4F07-AF01-2DD57999DC12}/en/1/xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/{548EB4E1-0CCD-4F07-AF01-2DD57999DC12}/en/1/xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/Branches/{7BB0FC4E-D974-4C0F-AB17-AE31506465D4}/en/1/xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/Branches/Sitecore Queue Processors Root/{789EB5EC-3A75-4FD7-A43A-DA7D3D64DD26}/en/1/xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 INFO  Installing item: items/master/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/Branches/Sitecore Queue Processors Root/Sitecore/Update Queue Processors/{06DCBD20-DC35-4945-87F3-B687323F6DAA}/en/1/xml
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 ERROR Data template '{7B75BE5C-D34B-4D25-A3AC-D2C268C26A65}' not found for item '/sitecore/templates/Branches/Data Exchange/Providers/Sitecore/Branches/Sitecore Queue Processors Root/Sitecore/Update Queue Processors' in 'master' database
>   ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
>   Exception[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsLhI.png): System.NullReferenceException 
>   Message[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsLhI.png): Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>   Source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsLhI.png): Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions 
>      at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.ItemExtensions.InheritsFrom(Item item, ID templateId)
>      at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.EventHandlers.VariantCacheClearer.IsRenderingVariant(Item item)
>      at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.EventHandlers.VariantCacheClearer.OnItemSaved(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #15 16:48:07 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID: {06DCBD20-DC35-4945-87F3-B687323F6DAA}, database: master
>   Exception: System.AggregateException
>   Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
>      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
>   ...

Comment: Please look into Sitecore logs and included related errors into your question.

Comment: Highly possible this is the same issue: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/864/error-upgrading-to-sxa-1-1-with-publishing-service-1-8-itemlocator-language-ca/881#881

Comment: Definitely need more information in order to try to diagnose the problem. I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the Publishing Framework and retry?

Comment: No not yet. Hoping to help others reproduce the issue before I go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you install the packages in the order described in the installation guide.

From the looks of the log, you are installing the Sitecore provider, but one of the templates from the framework is not available. This error will occur when you install the Sitecore provider package *before* you install the framework package.

Comment: Still trying to duplicate the issue with a fresh install. Perhaps that is the sequence I did by mistake.

Comment: I hope you fail! :-)

Comment: Oh. Try this. SC 8.2, Publishing Framework, Data Framework. Error.

Comment: I was not able to replicate that. Can you try temporarily disabling the config files for the publishing service and then try to reinstall Data Exchange Framework?

Comment: Sure. I'll provide more detailed steps for tomorrow and update my question.

Comment: And please include names of all of the files you are using, including Sitecore itself. I want to try to replicate your environment as closely as possible.

Comment: Will do. Reminds me that I have configs for CMS only mode too. Probably end up doing a before and after snapshot of the files.